# Suggestion Power Supply Design to drive inductive load

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, driver, mosfet-driver

I need to drive inductive load (Helmholtz coil) with power requirement of V = 800V and I= 10A. Planning to use FET based half-bridge circuitry to achieve this. If anyone has better solution to this please post your feedback.

Comment: I think this is highly suitable for a SiC bridge. Parts with 1200 V and more rating are readily available.

Comment: AC or DC?  Carrier frequency (if AC) and bandwidth?

Comment: @TimWescott Its DC supply.

Comment: What range of voltages do you want to apply?  Up to 800, I assume.  Do you want to go negative?  How _fast_ do you want to change voltage?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to fill in these blanks.

Comment: Half-bridge? I'd consider a full-bridge, maybe PSFB.

Comment: Yikes, what inductance? A full bridge, with shorting capability as @JohnD hints, sounds like a good idea to deal with the stored energy, otherwise a lot of capacitance may be required.

Comment: @TimWilliams or an inexpensive switching shunt drive as we have discussed recently  Probably cheaper than another half bridge. The real question is if both ends of the load are accessible and if the 800 V supply can be made +/-400 V or if bipolar drive is even needed.

Comment: I would rather an H-bridge over a bipolar supply, but there may be reasons for either. And indeed, a shunt load might be used to handle overvoltage instead of capacitance; @tobalt's situation (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651658/output-ovp-ratings-in-isolated-ac-dc-converter) is identical, as I understand it.